# Fixing slider alignment with background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a slider containing a set of images. I want to fit the slider exactly into the (screen) background image of an iphone. The issue I am facing is that the slider and background images are not aligning properly as I want them to. I am a new to web development so can anyone guide me as how to align the slider to the background image. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks. 
My code is [here](https://github.com/iyerkiran/Sample_Slider)

Comment: Can we have a fiddle demo please.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble but I am finding it a bit complex to represent it in fiddle. Can you try it this way it would be really helpful.

Comment: Do you have full image of the mobile because as i am seeing its half cut.

Comment: half is enough for me @Steevan

Answer (score 0):

In order to align elements and help simplify the development for mobile devices, CSS 3 Offers, among others, the media-query.

You can read all about CSS3 and walk through the tutorial at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_intro.asp)

It is very helpful and easy guide for beginners in this section.